# Question about Java class constructor

Tags: java

Can somebody tell me what does this mean? I'm going trough Java book and I've encontered this example :

```
public class Message {

    Message(){}

    public Message(String text){
        this.text = text;
    }
```

What does `Message(){}` Mean ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a package private empty constructor taking no arguments.

You can use it to create a new Message instance from any code in the same package, by using `new Message();`.

It's worthwhile to know it will not initialize the `text` field, which will therefore hold the default `null` value.

Comment: I think it would be interesting to add the fact that the good point is that no one can use the default constructor outside of the class, so the user is forced to give the text parameter

Comment: @Valentin: Nope, that's private your thinking about.. This is package-private (also known as default), which is accessible anywhere from the same package.

Comment: my bad, seems like I'm not really awake today :/

Answer (score 1):

just like

```
Message()
{
}
```

but using less lines.

the access level for it is the (default) package access level meaning only classes within the same package can instantiate this object using this constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The class Message defines two constructors.  The first (the default constructor) is scoped to package-level visability.  That means that only classes within the same package can execute code that looks like:

```
Message msg = new Message();
```

All classes outside of the package must call the second constructor.